# Parallelizing / speeding up a replacement rule over large list

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, series-expansion

I have a list of differentiated expression of the form `{f[0,0,0],(f^(a,b,c))[0,0,0],...}` where I have left the function as a general `f[x,y,z]`, and `(f^(a,b,c))[0,0,0]` is the derivative w.r.t. x `a` times evaluated at `[x,y,z]=[0,0,0]`. The list itself is output from a power series expansion

```
 Tn[n_] := Normal[Series[f[x,y,z],{x,0,n},{y,0,n},{z,0,n}]]
 TnList[n_]:=List@@Tn[n]
```

After some additional operations that reduce the number of terms I'm using, I want to substitute and evaluate the list for a specific function. I have tried numerous options, mainly of the form

```
 fMap[n_] := Map[ReplaceAll[f-> Function[{x,y,z},Exp[-U[x,y,z]]], TnList[n]]
```

However, if I try going past say a 3rd order expansion (`n=3`), the time to evaluate the list starts drastically increasing. I have also tried

```
 Parallelize[fMap[n]]
```

but have seen very minimal change, such that I can't even tell if it's doing anything different. Sadly, CUDAMap doesn't work on symbols, so that's also ruled out.

Can anyone suggest a method to speed up this process? It's the only bottleneck in my notebook, and I'd like to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried ParallelMap instead of Map and then Parallelize ?

Comment: Can you provide a realistic example without an undefined function `U`? It's not the replacement that takes long, it's the evaluation of the derivatives which is the bottleneck.

Comment: I have tried ParallelMap as well, and saw a similar performance. The function I'm including looks like:  `U[x,y,z] := A(x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2) +B(x^2  y^2 z^2) `

Comment: I realize this process needs to constantly evaluate the same derivatives over and over again, so is there an efficient way to store the previous //Simplify'd solutions instead of constantly recalculating them?